# iMacros radio button csv file

Tags: csv, radio-button, imacros

I am using iMacros to fill a form. It contains 4 radio buttons with the IDs `rbCorrect_0`, `rbCorrect_1`, `rbCorrect_2`, `rbCorrect_3` and I have to select one of them. Other fields I am filling from a CSV file which works fine.

Here is the working code:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=ID:adminForm ATTR=ID:rbCorrect_0
```

or

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=ID:adminForm ATTR=ID:rbCorrect_1
```

etc...

What I want is to pass this value from the CSV file. For some fields it is `rbCorrect_1`, for others it is `rbCorrect_0` and so on... I have a column in the CSV file having this value.

The question is how to do this?

---

This is the radio button field as defined in the form:

```html
<td style="text-align: center;">
    <input type="radio" onclick="aris_updateHidCorrect()" name="rbCorrect" id="rbCorrect" value="true" />
</td>
```

Comment: <td style="text-align: center;"><input type="radio" onclick="aris_updateHidCorrect()" name="rbCorrect" id="rbCorrect" value="true" /></td>

This is the radio button field as defined in form. Please help guys..

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to do this..

The code is like

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=ID:adminForm ATTR=ID:{{!COL6}}
```

Make sure the value which is being posted is there in the column as such.